# Nodejs Email attachment issue browse file through Postman form-data

Tags: node.js, json, postman, backend, email-attachments

Hi,
I am Facing issues with the Email attachment,
Please tell me how can i send file that i browse from form-data in postman.
how to refer the path of that file?

```
//const Joi = require('joi');
const express = require('express'); //This returns a function
const app = express(); 
app.use(express.json());
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var send = require('gmail-send');
var fileupload = require('express-fileupload'); 
app.use(fileupload());
var config = require('./config.json')
const Joi = require('joi');
```

This is the Post method for validating the email data.

//POST

```
app.post('/api/sendemail', (req, res) => {

    //No need to validate using JOI, Email validation is done using sendMail()
    const schema = {
        to: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
        subject: Joi.string().min(1).required(),
        text: Joi.string()
    };
    const result = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);

    if (result.error) {
        res.status(400).send(result.error);
        return;
    }
```

Transporter variable contains the sending info.

```
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465, 
        ssl: 'true',
        auth: {
            user: config.sender, 
            pass: config.password 
        },
    });
```

In this Mail Info Look at Attachments,how to right the path?

```
    let Mailinfo = {

        from: config.sender,
        to: req.body.to,
        subject: req.body.subject,
        text: req.body.text,
        attachments: [
            { filename: req.files } 
                    ]
    }
```

```
    transporter.sendMail(Mailinfo, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
        } else {
            console.log(req.files);
            res.send('Email sent successfully' + info.response);

        }

    });

});
```

Here is the POrt connection

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}....`));
```

Comment: Wherever config.sender or config.password is written replace it with 
'your email id and password'

Answer (score 0):

You can use sendgrid api with :

```
npm install @sendgrid/mail


const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')

sgMail.setApiKey(yourapikey)

let msg = {
     to: email,
     from: your email,
     subject: your subject,
     text: your text,
     html: your html file,
}

await sgMail.end(msg)
```